# Create a new list from a list when a certain condition is met

Tags: python, list, append, conditional-statements

I want to make a new list from another list of words; when a certain condition of the word is met. In this case I want to add all words that have the length of 9 to a new list.

I have used :

```
resultReal = [y for y in resultVital if not len(y) < 4]
```

to remove all entries that are under the length of 4. However, I do not want to remove the entries now. I want to create a new list with the words, but keeping them in the old list.

Perhaps something like this:

```
if len(word) == 9:
     newlist.append()
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sorry, realized you wanted length, 9, not length 9 or greater.

```
newlist = [word for word in words if len(word) == 9]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
newlist = []
for item in resultVital:
    if len(item) == 9:
        newlist.append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
newlist = [word for word in words if len(word) == 9]
```

Comment: Check the formatting hints on the bottom, right side of the edit page.  Please format your code properly to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list= [list_word for list_word in words if len(list_word) == 1]
```