# Python, create new list based on condition applied to an existing list of same length

Tags: python, list, numpy

Ok, I'm sure there is a very easy way to do this, but I'm rusty in python and I can't work out the pythonic way to do this.

I have a list, representing the hours of the day:

```
import numpy as np
hourOfDay = np.mod(range(0, 100), 24)
```

Then I want to create a new list which is a larger value `0.4`, when the hour is between `7` and `22`, and `0.2` otherwise.

There are several related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147696/python-how-to-create-a-new-list-based-on-existing-list-without-certain-objects) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7406448/python-create-a-new-list-from-a-list-when-a-certain-condition-is-met), but they're not quite what I want (they end up with a shorter list, I want the same-length list).

Assuming I needed to use list comprehension I tried this:

```
newList = [0.4 for hour in hourOfDay if hour <= 7 or hour >= 22 else 0.2]
```

Comment: Almost perfect; `for` goes in the end of the list comp, conditions go first: `newList = [0.4 if hour <= 7 or hour >= 22 else 0.2 for hour in hourOfDay]`

Comment: Thanks @AndrasDeak! Ashamed I didn't get there on my own; but at least this'll be here for me to find next time I forget how python works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension was slightly off. Also if you want `0.4` when the hour is between `7` and `22`, you need `7<= hour <= 22`:

```
import numpy as np
hourOfDay = np.mod(range(0, 100), 24)

newList = [0.4 if 7 <= i <= 22 else 0.2 for i in hourOfDay]

>>> newList
[0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mask, but note that for refusing of type casting you should create the first array with data type float.:

```
In [15]: hourOfDay = np.mod(range(0, 100), 24, dtype=np.float)

In [16]: mask = np.logical_or(hourOfDay <= 7, hourOfDay >= 22)

In [17]: hourOfDay[mask] = 0.4

In [19]: hourOfDay[~mask] = 0.2

In [20]: hourOfDay
Out[20]: 
array([ 0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,
        0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,
        0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.2,
        0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,
        0.2,  0.2,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,
        0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,
        0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,
        0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,
        0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.2,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,  0.4,
        0.4])
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the alternative approach is to use `map()` as:

```
map(lambda x: 0.4 if 7 <= x <= 22 else 0.2, hourOfDay)
```